# Localizable Entities in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core-localization

I'm using **'IStringLocalizer'** in controllers to localize static data on my website! ([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization))

but, What is the best approach to localize entities like NewsEntity or PostEntity?
or how to code localizable entities?

```
public class News : BaseEntity
{
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
{Joking}
public class News : BaseEntity
{
     public string TitleEn { get; set; }
     public string BodyEn { get; set; }

     public string TitleDe { get; set; }
     public string BodyDe { get; set; }
     ...
}
```

Comment: You mean users write into database title in multiple languages, and you want a correct title to be used based on which language user selected?

Comment: @Erndob ! Yes! Exactly

Comment: Where are your current localized strings stored, the static ones. In database too or .resx files?

Comment: current localized string stored in .resx files! as mentioned in link!

Comment: You could create a separate resources table in database. Smart caching to make it fast. Then your news entity would point to a resource key. And then different tables for each language would point to the resource with their text. Maybe not sql database but some key-value store to make it a lot faster. Or you could have it the same way you have it now. But have wrapper on those entities. "TranslatedNews". Which is same, but instead of having a property for each language, it would have just one. And then a generic method that maps from regular entity to translated model based on current lang.

Comment: Interesting, and i would assume common problem though. If no one answers, after work I will look into it more for better solutions.

Comment: one way is using the [SmartStore](https://github.com/smartstoreag/SmartStoreNET) or [NopCommerce](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce) approach for localizing entities! but that's very complex to use! I need a simple way to handle it!

Comment: Hey @Erndob ! did you find any way to do that?

Comment: Hey. Sorry for the long wait. I answered now. I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

For this class:

```
public class News : BaseEntity
{
   public string TitleEn { get; set; }
   public string BodyEn { get; set; }
   public string TitleDe { get; set; }
   public string BodyDe { get; set; }
}
```

You could do something like this:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
   protected bool IsGerman => Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == "de"
}

public class News : BaseEntity
{
   public string Title => IsGerman ? TitleDe : TitleEn

   public string Body => IsGerman ? BodyDe : BodyEn

   public string TitleEn { get; set; }
   public string BodyEn { get; set; }
   public string TitleDe { get; set; }
   public string BodyDe { get; set; }
}
```

For more extensibility, you could change your database structure. Instead of News table having strings for every language. You could have a table like this:

```
dbo.News
TitleResource: ResourceId
BodyResource: ResourceId

dbo.Resource
ResourceId: int

dbo.Language
LanguageId: int
LanguageName: string

dbo.ResourceValue
ResourceValueId
ResourceId
Value: string
LanguageId
```

This way, any table that has different strings per language, instead of storing the language itself, it would store an Id to a resource for that string. And then there would be multiple ResourceValues with strings for different languages, pointing to the same Resource.
All the possible language choices would be in the Language table. This way, if you add a new language, you won't need to change a single line in the code, just add a new row in Language table, and the code should pick it up and know how to resolve strings to that language, and suggest users to fill that language.